# 'RcppArmadillo.h' file not found when installing RcppArmadillo from source

Tags: r, rcpp

RcppArmadillo 0.8.400.0.0 works just fine on my computer, both from sourceCpp and cxxfunction. Now I want to upgrade to 0.8.500.0, which requires compilation from source. Then I got the error

```
ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio128/concert/include -DIL_STD -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
RcppArmadillo.cpp:22:10: fatal error: 'RcppArmadillo.h' file not found
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I got this error whether I ran `install.packages("RcppArmadillo")` in RStudio or in R console outside RStudio. My compiler is clang4, and I have no problem installing RcppParallel or compiling my own Rcpp code that uses RcppArmadillo and RcppParallel. R version: 3.5.0, MacOS High Sierra.

Edit: I looked at https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/143, which is very relevant. I did install clang6 and gfortran 6.1, both downloaded from the CRAN website. I also changed the `.R/Makevars` file to reflect the changes to clang6. I have also installed `ccache` as suggested, to make compilation faster. Here's my `Makevars`:

```
F77 = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
FC = $F77
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
CC=ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang
SHLIB_CXXLD=ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++  -Wall
CXX1X= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX98= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX11= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX14= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX17= ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang6/lib
```

From the outputs in the R console when I was installing the package (added to the error message above), I can tell that clang6 was used for compilation. I also found the downloaded RcppArmadillo tarball, unpacked it, and ran `./configure` from the command line. Nothing seemed wrong there; no `config.log` file was generated. This doesn't seem to be a configuration problem. Then I still got the exact same error when trying to install the package in R, after configuration, in libs. I also didn't get any message about `-fopenmp`. It seems that my problem is a bit different from that in the GitHub ticket.

Comment: See the github issue tickets, there was _extensive_ discussion about what you need to setup on macOS.  It also matters which compiler installation you used.  This was one thread: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/223 but there are others. Also consider asking in rcpp-devel.  (I don't have a macOS machine so I cannot really help.)

Answer (score 1):

R 3.5.x requires `clang6` and adding `clang6` to your system `PATH` variable.

Steps:

x Download and install the [clang-6.0.0.pkg](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/clang-6.0.0.pkg) official package from CRAN.

x Delete your `~/.R/Makevars` as it is likely set to use `clang4`. To do this, open Terminal and type:

```
sudo rm ~/.R/Makevars
```

x Then add to your `~/.bash_profile` the following:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/clang6/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/clang6/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

**Note:** If you are using a shell other than *bash* you **will** need to add the above into the appropriate file, e.g. for `zsh` add to `~/.zshrc`, as this was not implemented in the official installer.

I should have a few cycles to finish writing a new *unofficial* Rtools installer a bit later. See: https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-rtools/issues/7

**Note:** Alternatively, you can remove the paths individual with

```
sudo vi ~/.R/Makevars
```

Pressing `I` to enter insert mode, deleting lines with `clang4` in the path, and then pressing `ESC` + `:wq` to write changes to file.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this problem went away with version 0.8.600. Later, this problem appeared again when I upgraded to RcppArmadillo 0.9.100.5.0. Somehow I only got this error when building from source; I downloaded the binary manually from the CRAN website, and used `R CMD INSTALL` to install the prebuilt version, and it worked; somehow R doesn't seem to know that there is a binary available for the newest version.

I did install clang6 and modified `.R/Makevars` to use clang6, but the same problem persisted; probably something else caused the problem.